# Перенос формы с другого сайта на свой

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

http://kuponator.ru/?invite=actionpay смотрите, вот сайт скидок. тут есть такая панелька где вводится email и выбирается город. Моя цель с другого сайта по реф ссылке перенести пользователя на этот сайт скидок. Но проблема в том что многие видят эту ужаснуб страницу и не регаются. Так вот что я хотел бы: Перенести подобную панельку с данными на сайт мой и потом, когда пользователь переходит по реф ссылке, на этом сайте скидок графы заполнялись автоматически и он переходил дальше сразу к акциям. вот реально это сделать? =)

Answer (score 1):

Если интересует принцип - надо посмотреть с какими файлами общается это зеленое безобразие и напрвить туда же соответствующие запросы по http_request() прямо из PHP. Потом сказать, что пользователю пришла ссылка на e-mail, по которой он сам отправится за скидками.

Comment: но мне надо чтобы засчитался переход по реф-ссылке.
можно ли по принципу анонимайзера сделать? 
то есть я скачиваю страницу по запросу пользователя. вырезаем ненужное и отдаем чисто форму пользователю. можно ли так?

Comment: Вряд ли: это аяксовая страница, она скорее всего не даст отправить с себя запрос.

Comment: а если попробывать перенести все города себе в базу?

Comment: Пересоздать форму можно. Я сказал как. Проблема в том, чтобы ТОТ сайт поверил, чтоего заполняет живой человек